# Installing docpad@6.63 error: No compatible version found: taskgroup@'~3.3.7n'

Tags: docpad

I'm trying to install docpad and following the guide on: http://docpad.org/docs/install

When I issue the command:

```
npm install -g docpad@6.63
```

I get the following npm error:

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: taskgroup@'~3.3.7n'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["2.0.0","3.0.0","3.1.0","3.1.1","3.1.2","3.2.0","3.2.2","3.2.3","3.2.4","3.3.0","3.3.1","3.3.2","3.3.3","3.3.4","3.3.5","3.3.6","3.3.7","3.3.8"]
```

My node version: v0.10.15

My npm version: 1.2.18

I'm running Kubuntu 13.10 with all updates.

I checked if there is an issue reported for this on github, there isn't. Should I report this as an issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please do report this as an issue in GitHub. I've come across this issue myself but I keep forgetting to report it. Also add I'm on Arch Linux. :)

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here (Kubuntu 13.10).

I sugggest to go back to a previous version of docpad for the moment. On Ubunto/Debian there is another pitfall: some node modules depend on the nodejs executable to be available under node, so you need the additional package nodejs-legacy.

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
npm install docpad@6.55.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Bug on DocPad's behalf, that `n` shouldn't have been there. Now fixed in v6.63.5. Thanks for the report!